# Linear equation system over field $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, systems-of-equations, finite-fields

Could somebody please have a look at my attempt to solve this LES? It's the first time I'm solving a LES over a residue class so I'm not quite sure if it's right.

> Solve the given linear equation system over $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.
>
> For simplicity, let $[\lambda] \hat{=} \lambda$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

What I did:

$\left(\begin{array}{@{}cccc|c@{}}
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0
\end{array}\right)$ $\text{II-I;} \space \text{III-2} \cdot \text{I;} \space \text{IV-I} \leadsto$ $\left(\begin{array}{@{}cccc|c@{}}
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 2
\end{array}\right) \\ $

II and III are identical, thus $x_4$ can be choosen arbitrarily.

Let $x_4 = \lambda$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

II (or III) yields: $x_2 = [0] - [2\lambda] = [-2] \cdot \lambda = [1] \cdot \lambda = \lambda$,

IV yields: $x_3=[2]-[2\lambda] = [2]+[-2]\cdot[\lambda] = [2]+[1]\cdot\lambda = [2+\lambda]$ and

I yields: $x_1 = [1] - [2\lambda] - [4+2\lambda] - [2\lambda] = [1]+[\lambda]-[1+2\lambda]+[\lambda] = [1+\lambda-1-2\lambda+\lambda] = [0]$.

The solution set $\mathbb{L}$ therefore is 
$$\mathbb{L} = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} [0]\\ [\lambda] \\ [2+\lambda] \\ [\lambda] \end{pmatrix}\right\}$$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

Also: Would the solution set be any different if the field was $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, as no coefficient is bigger than $[3]$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As for why the solutions are different, it's easiest to just think in dimension 1: what is the solution to $[2]x=[1]$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and $\mathbb{Z}_5$?

Comment: It would be $x = [2]$ in $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{3Z}$ and $x = [3] \ne [2]$ in $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{5Z}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is right.

Regarding the original LES, it holds that:

I: $[2\lambda]+[4]+[2\lambda] + [2\lambda] = [6\lambda] + [4] = [1]$,

II: $[4]+[2\lambda]+[\lambda]=[4]+[3\lambda]=[1]$,

III: $[2\lambda]+[2]+[\lambda]=[3\lambda]+[2]=[2]$ and

IV: $[\lambda]+[2\lambda]=[3\lambda]=[0]$.

Answer (score 1):

The solution set is different over $\Bbb Z_5$ for the simple reason that $\lambda$ would range over elements of $\Bbb Z_5$ instead of $\Bbb Z_3$.

Comment: Got that, thanks!